# Google Maps API v3: Mulitple DirectionsRequests need different time to be answered

Tags: java, gwt, google-maps-api-3

I want to draw five different routes in Google Maps API v3, GWT 2.5.1. I initialize a route which sets its `DirectionDisplay` and `DirectionsRequest` in this class.

When I start my web project, sometimes only my first route is shown, sometimes all five, so I decided to make a `System.out.print(m)`;.

The results:

- 01234 ->  as expected, all routes shown
- 10234 ->  error, only first route shown.

Why does Google serve my second request before my first? I tried to use `Thread.sleep(1000)` to ensure that my requests have time to come back in order, also Timer/TimerTasks, no success. Any ideas?

```
DirectionsService o = DirectionsService.newInstance();

for (Integer i = 0; i < 4; i++) {  //routes.size()

    final int m = i;

    final Route route = new Route("Route " + i.toString());

    route.initRoute(m, getRoutingPresenter(), adressData, addressIndex);
    //here i initialize the DirectionsRequests and its Displays, which
    //i set in this class after execution.

    o.route(directionsRequest, new DirectionsResultHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onCallback(DirectionsResult result,DirectionsStatus status) {

            if (status == DirectionsStatus.OK) {

                   System.out.print(m);
                       ...
            }
        }
    );
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Google can take as long as they like to handle your requests and you should code accordingly. This is true of any HTTP traffic. Even if the remote server guaranteed a fixed service time for all requests, the Internet does not and your requests could be taking any old route through it.

You can either right your handling code so that the response order doesn't matter, or write it so that it waits until all responses are back and then sort out the order itself.

I would recommend the first unless there are very specific an important reasons not to.